# What is all that diner lingo in Stargate SG-1 episode "Threads"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the *Stargate SG-1* episode "Threads", Oma Desala appears as a waitress in a diner. She calls out orders to the cook in diner lingo, much of it going by rather quickly. What are all the diner lingo items she calls for, and what is the lay-speak for each of those items?

Comment: Could you show us the words in question? At least find a clip that we can hear?

Comment: I haven't seen the episode, but [this online dictionary](http://www.dinerlingo.com/) of diner lingo should have your answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The line was:

> **OMA:** *Excuse me. Frank, I need a Noah's boy in a blanket, two hens
> fruit wrecked on a shingle with a mystery in the alley, a warm Eve
> with a moldy lid, and two checkerboards, alright?* [She tears off the
> order and pins it over the counter] *Oh yeah, hold the pig.*

Courtesy of [Mala50 on the Gateworld site](https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/20631-Oma-s-Waitressspeak)

> **Noah's boy:** Slice of [ham](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_(son_of_Noah)).
> **Blanket:** Sandwich
> **Hen Fruit:** Eggs
> **Wrecked:** Scrambled
> **Shingle:** Toast
> **Mystery in the Alley:** [A side of hash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253748/why-is-a-mystery-in-the-alley-a-side-of-hash/253761#253761) (h/t to our colleagues on English:SE)
> **Eve with a Moldy Lid:** Apple pie with a slice of cheese
> **Checkerboard:** A waffle
> **Pig:** Bacon

---

Later she mentions "motor oil" (**Maple Syrup**), "Joe" (**Coffee**) and "her dogs" (**Feet**)

Comment: (+1) Most of those make sense, but why is "mystery in the alley" a side of hash? (Also, wow. Until now, I had no idea that apple pie with a slice of cheese was a thing!)

Comment: @ruakh - http://homecookingmemories.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Apple-Pie-MIB3-5.jpg

Comment: Yeah -- by "Until now" I meant, "Until reading your answer and doing a Google Image Search for that part". :-P

Comment: @ruakh - I'll confess to never having heard of such a thing.

Comment: "Noah's boy" made me choke on my tea.

Comment: @ruakh - Asked and answered for you; [Why is a “Mystery in the Alley” a side of hash?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253748/why-is-a-mystery-in-the-alley-a-side-of-hash/253761#253761)

Comment: @Richard: Thanks!

Comment: To my ear, it sounded almost exactly like the quote posted on the Gateworld site quoted above: "Frank, I need a noseboy and a blanket. Two handfruit wrecked on a shingle with a mystery in the alley. A warmy with a mouldy lid and two checkerboards, alright?" Looking up diner lingo would have gotten me nowhere with "noseboy" or "warmy". It either needed a discerning or informed ear to decode the apparent "noseboy" to "Noah's boy" and "warmy" to "warm Eve". I didn't have as much trouble with "hen fruit".

Comment: @Kreiri, a "Noah's boy" makes perfect sense when you consider that Noah had 3 sons, named Shem, Japheth, and Ham. So of those 3 Ham makes the most sense as a food item...so "Noah's boy in a blanket" becomes "Ham Sandwich" (could also substitute "wrap"for "sandwich" I suppose, but I don't know diner lingo well enough...may depend on the diner)

Comment: @JesseJoslyn - I did briefly consider the other potential references for 'in blanket' (e.g. "wrapped in pastry" and "in a bread bun") but coupled with ham, this seemed the only phrase that fit.